# What is wrong with my PBKDF2 in Node here?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, cryptography, pbkdf2

Can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong here, I can't get the same hash twice nor validate a password so specs 2 and 4 are failing. Does anyone see any obvious issues here that is causing me to have problems with generating the same hash twice? I'm using node v8.9.1 (and Typescript 2.6.1 which shouldn't matter I hope). I've tried using only Buffers and base64 strings (below) but nothing has worked.

**Implementation:**

```
import { pbkdf2Sync, randomBytes } from 'crypto';

export class Auth {
  private iters = 1e1; // TODO: increase later
  private keylen = 64;
  private digest = 'sha512';

  create(password: string) {
    const salt = randomBytes(128);

    const hash = pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, this.iters, this.keylen, this.digest);

    console.log(hash.toString('hex'));

    return [salt.toString('base64'), hash.toString('base64'), this.iters].join('::');
  }

  verify(stored: string, password: string) {
    const [salt, hash, iters] = stored.split('::');

    const verify = pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, parseInt(iters, 10), this.keylen, this.digest);

    console.log(verify.toString('hex'));

    return hash === verify.toString('base64');
  }
}
```

**Specs:**

```
  describe('Auth', () => {
  const auth = new Auth();
  const password = 'test';

  it('should hash a password', () => {
    const hash = auth.create(password);

    expect(hash).to.be.string;
  });

  it('should verify valid password', () => {
    const hash = auth.create(password);
    const valid = auth.verify(hash, password);

    expect(valid).to.be.true;
  });

  it('should reject invalid password', () => {
    const hash = auth.create(password);
    const invalid = auth.verify(hash, 'wrong input');

    expect(invalid).to.be.false;
  });
});

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've pinpointed my bug. I falsely assumed that since pbkdf2 accepts either a Buffer or a string that it would work with a Buffer, however I was storing the salt in base64 to later verify it with pdkdf2 would result in a different salt being used.

In case someone comes across this:

```
// tslint:disable:no-shadowed-variable
import { pbkdf2Sync, randomBytes } from 'crypto';

export class Auth {
  private iters = 1e1; // TODO: increase later
  private keylen = 64;
  private digest = 'sha512';

  create(password: string) {
    const salt = randomBytes(128).toString('base64'); // <- salt 
    // salt was not base64 before being used by pbkdf2

    const hash = pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, this.iters, this.keylen, this.digest).toString('base64');

    return [salt, hash, this.iters].join('::');
  }

  verify(stored: string, password: string) {
    const [salt, hash, iters] = stored.split('::');
    const verify = pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, parseInt(iters, 10), this.keylen, this.digest);

    return hash === verify.toString('base64');
  }
}
```

Comment: How are u able to use crypto module?, went around in circles searching for a solution but still facing error that no module found crypto.

Comment: crypto is in the more recent nodejs releases standard lib, what version of node are you using? check if crypto is included

Comment: I am using 8.11.1 as per the docs it says it is included also did a check if such module is present in my local system , seems it is present , also managed to do run a small individual  **.js**  program using crypo module , but for some reason cannot use in Angular **.ts**

Comment: crypto is a NodeJS module (server-side). You can't use crypto in the browser (Angular)

Comment: Isn't `return hash === verify.toString('base64');` vulnerable to timing attacks?

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to be able to generate the same PBKDF2 hash twice, that is the point of the random seed.

WRT verifying you are Base64 encoding the salt and hash in `create` but not Base64 decoding them in `verify`.

For debugging display the inputs and outputs of `pbkdf2` for both `create` and `verify`, use hex for binary values such as `salt` and `hash` and add that to the question. This may be enough for you to see the error.

When debugging make things as simple as possible, using call backs adds a level of debugging complexity.

Comment: Thank you I see what you mean by same hash twice.

Comment: I've updated my post with a synchronous version but alas, I am still getting a different hash when trying to `verify`

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, see my own answer below